# How can a React Native view respond to external (hardware) keyboard events?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to support iPad (and improve my debugging experience), by allowing a React Native screen to respond to a keyboard shortcut, say the standard `⌘[`, and to then navigation back to the previous page.

The navigation is easy enough, but how do I listen for a keyboard shortcut within a component?

The React Native documentation for [Keyboard](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#__docusaurus) or "input" offers no advice at all.

Comment: Do you mean a hardware keyboard?

Comment: Yes, a hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-keyevent](https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent#usage) package and add the event listener on your component.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // if you want to react to keyDown
    KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
      console.log(`onKeyDown keyCode: ${keyEvent.keyCode}`);
      console.log(`Action: ${keyEvent.action}`);
      console.log(`Key: ${keyEvent.pressedKey}`);
    });

    // if you want to react to keyUp
    KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyEvent) => {
      console.log(`onKeyUp keyCode: ${keyEvent.keyCode}`);
      console.log(`Action: ${keyEvent.action}`);
      console.log(`Key: ${keyEvent.pressedKey}`);
    });

    // if you want to react to keyMultiple
    KeyEvent.onKeyMultipleListener((keyEvent) => {
      console.log(`onKeyMultiple keyCode: ${keyEvent.keyCode}`);
      console.log(`Action: ${keyEvent.action}`);
      console.log(`Characters: ${keyEvent.characters}`);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm a little sad that there's no native way to do this.  That library is pretty limited (can't do multiple keystrokes on iOS) but it's certainly appreciated.

Comment: I am glad it works for you and I agree we need a better way of doing this. I think with the new iPad Pro coming with a pretty good keyboard and touchpad, it will become more crucial to have a native way of capturing these events and we will have it:). have a nice day.